# WKWebview get content height, always return with some extra space

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I am trying to get html content's height or scrollview's proper content height from WKWebview. But it always gives some extra height.

I used two approaches.

1.Using evaluate javascript in didFinishNavigation

```
 [webView evaluateJavaScript: @"document.body.offsetHeight"
     completionHandler: ^ (id _Nullable string, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         CGRect webViewFrame = webView.frame;
         webViewFrame.size.height = [(NSString * ) string floatValue];
         [webView setFrame: webViewFrame];

 ];
```

2.Using KVO for webView.scrollView's content size.

```
CGSize changedSize = CGSizeFromString(change[@"new"]);
   CGRect webViewFrame = webView.frame;
   webViewFrame.size.height = height;
   [webView webViewFrame];
```

Neither of the above approach works.With content size KVO approach, few times I could see a proper height but not all the time.

Comment: Did you finally manage to get or calculate `WKWebView` height? The answer may be useful for other users.